# An example of how pytorch clip_grad_norm_ works

Tags: pytorch, gradient, gradient-exploding

I'd like a simple example to illustrate how gradient clipping via clip_grad_norm_ works. From [this](https://neptune.ai/blog/understanding-gradient-clipping-and-how-it-can-fix-exploding-gradients-problem) post, I found that if the norm of a gradient is greater than a threshold, then it simply takes the unit vector of the gradient and multiplies it with with threshold. That's what I tried

```
v = torch.rand(5)*1000
v_1 = v.clone()
torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(v_1, max_norm=1.0, norm_type=2)
print(v, v_1)

(tensor([381.2621, 935.3613, 664.9132, 840.0740, 443.0156]),
 tensor([381.2621, 935.3613, 664.9132, 840.0740, 443.0156]))
```

I'd have thought it would do `v/torch.norm(v, p=2) * 2` which should give me `tensor([0.2480, 0.6083, 0.4324, 0.5463, 0.2881])`

It doesn't seem to do anything. I thought the max_norm was the threshold value (the [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_.html) wasn't very clear on this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716377/how-to-do-gradient-clipping-in-pytorch) post wasn't too helpful either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm` clips the gradients values (accessed via `Tensor.grad`) and not the values themselves. Quick example of use:

```py
v = torch.rand(5) * 1000
v_1 = v.clone()
v.requires_grad_(True)
v_1.requires_grad_(True)

loss = 1/2 * torch.sum(v_1 * v_1 + v * v)
# Here grads of loss w.r.t v and v_1 should be v and v_1 respectively
loss.backward()

# Clip grads of v_1
torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(v_1, max_norm=1.0, norm_type=2)

print(v.grad)
print(v_1.grad)
print(v.grad / torch.norm(v.grad, p=2))
```

Results in:

```
tensor([486.8801, 481.7880, 172.6818, 659.4149,  62.8158])  # no clipped
tensor([0.5028, 0.4975, 0.1783, 0.6809, 0.0649])  # clipped!
tensor([0.5028, 0.4975, 0.1783, 0.6809, 0.0649])  # same values
```

Comment: Thank you! It'd be good to add print(v.grad / torch.norm(v.grad, p=2)) for clarity, although in this case v.grad is the same as v as you mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I made the change (and thank for my 1000th reputation point :p)